# Argument principle to count zeros

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: Let $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open set $p \in U$ and $f$ be a holomorphic function defined on $U$ so that $f(p) = f'(p) = 0$. Use the argument principle to prove the following statement: there exists $\delta>0$ so that if $0 < |Q|< \delta$ then $f^{-1}(Q)$ contains at least two points.

My attempt: I know $f$ has a zero of order at least $2$ at $p$, however I am unsure how to obtain the $\delta$ described in the question. Any hints are appreciated.

Let $\gamma$ denote $\{|z-p| = r\}$ where $r> 0$ so that $\overline{D(p,r)} \subset U$ and $f$ is non-vanishing on the deleted closed ball $\overline{D(p,r)} - \{p\}$. By the argument principle, we have $n(f \circ \gamma, f(p)) \geq 2$.

Comment: No, you *don't* know that $f$ has a zero of order $2$ at $p$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Wouldn't the following argument shows that $f$ has a zero of order 2 at $p$?
Since $f(p)=0$ then $f(z) = (z-p) g(z)$ where $g$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $p$. Taking derivative, we get $f'(z) =g(z) + (z-p)g'(z)$ and evaluating at $p$ we have $g(p) =0$ so $g$ has a zero at $p$. This concludes $f$ has a zero of order $2$ at $p$.

Comment: No. The conclusion is that $f$ has a zero of order *at least* $2$ at $p$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos you are right, my apologies.

Comment: the argument principle should tell you that you can come up with a simple closed curve $\gamma$ such that $n\big(f\circ \gamma, f(p)\big)\geq 2$... use compactness to argue for the existence of $\delta$ and finish with the fact that winding numbers are constant on a connected component  + Argument Principle.

Comment: Minor point, if $f=0$, it satisfies the conditions, but the above set is empty.

Comment: @user8675309 do you mind elaborating more about the compactness argument?

Comment: The question needs to mention that $f$ is non constant.

Comment: for non-constant $f$, its zeros are isolated so for $r\gt 0$ small enough the image of $f\circ \gamma$ is disjoint from $\big\{f(p)\big\}$ yet both sets are compact so there exists a minimum distance between the two and you can call this $\delta$

Comment: Also, note that the argument principle on its own does not show the existence of two **distinct** zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is non constant, hence the zeros are isolated. Choose $r>0$ such that **both** $f$ & $f'$ have no zeros in $\overline{B}(p,r)$ other than $p$ (the constraint on $f'$ is to ensure that any zero has multiplicity one). Let $\gamma(t) = p+r e^{2 \pi i t}$, and let $\Gamma$ be the range of $\gamma$.
Note that ${1 \over 2 \pi i}\int_\gamma {f' \over f} \ge 2$.

Let $\mu = \min_{z \in \Gamma} |f(z)|$ and choose $Q$ such that $0<|Q|<\mu$.
Let $f_Q = f-Q$.
Note that for $z \in \Gamma$, $|f_Q(z)| \ge |f(z)| -|Q| \ge \mu -|Q| > 0$.

Note that $\int_\gamma {f' \over f} = \int_{f \circ \gamma} {dz \over z} $.
Define the homotopy $H(t,s) = f_{sQ}(\gamma(t)) = f(\gamma(t)) - sQ$ and note that from the previous paragraph, the range of $H$ does not include zero, hence $\int_{f \circ \gamma} {dz \over z} = \int_{f_Q \circ \gamma} {dz \over z} \ge 2$ and so $f_Q$ contains at least two zeros (counting multiplicities).

Finally, note that if $z_Q$ is a zero of $f_Q$ in ${B}(p,r)$, then $f_Q'(z_Q) \neq 0$, and hence the zeros are simple.